# Extracting/scraping table from website - skipping over the table / information I want

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract some information from a website.

```
url <- "url <- "http://www.infocif.es/ficha-empresa/banco-santander-sa""
html <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)


html %>% .[[1]]
```

My current code gives me the following:

```
     RNK                    Razón Social    Ventas
1 NA  17  IBERDROLA GENERACION ESPAÑA SA 7.411.891
2 NA  18 GAS NATURAL COMERCIALIZADORA SA 6.280.546
3 NA  19         MERCEDES-BENZ ESPAÑA SA 5.542.579
```

The tables I am most interested in is the "first" one under the title: `Información de la compañía`.

I get the same result when I apply `readHTMLTable(url)`. So, is what I am trying to request actually not a table?

Comment: Do you want all the tables or just the first one? You say, "I want to extract all [the] tables in a list." And then say, "...I am most interested in the first one" -- which is it?

Comment: Thats a good point! I just want the first one. Or the table corresponding to `Información de la compañía`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will extract all the tables in a list:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.infocif.es/ficha-empresa/banco-santander-sa"

list_of_tables <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

If you just want the first one, you can extract it like normal with `[[`:

```
list_of_tables[[1]]
```

However...I don't think that's what you want. If you really want the elements from `Informacion de la compania`, I think you need to extract the elements from that ID:

```
text <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("#fe-informacion-izq .col-xs-12") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  # Clean-up the non-conforming text and special characters
  str_squish() %>% 
  # special case for Domicillo
  str_remove(pattern = "\\s\\{.*\\}")

names <- text[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
elements <- text[c(FALSE, TRUE)]

tibble(names, elements)

# A tibble: 11 x 2
   names                          elements                                      
   <chr>                          <chr>                                         
 1 CIF                            A39000013                                     
 2 Antigüedad                     163 años (21/03/1857)                         
 3 Domicilio                      Po Pereda 9-12 39004 - (Santander) - Cantabria
 4 Teléfono                       912737006                                     
 5 Registro                       Registro Mercantil de Madrid                  
 6 Web                            www.bancosantander.es                         
 7 Anterior Denominación:         BANCO SANTANDER CENTRAL HISPANO SA            
 8 Sector                         Intermediarios financieros                    
 9 Nº de empleados                -                                             
10 Cargos directivos - Presidente BOTIN SANZSAUTUOLA O'SHEA ANA PATRICIA Ver más
11 Matriz                         -
```